# Format range that is dynamically based on other cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

Take the following excel spreadsheet into consideration:

[image]

I would like to format the cells in row1:2 according to the values in cells A4:B7. If I change the values, the cells in row1:2 should be merged, bordered, filled, and text colored accordingly.

If I change the formatting cells to the following:

[image]

Comment: You can do everything but the merging part. Conditional formatting can handle the fill color and borders. Formulas can handle filling in the text. However, you can't get the merged and centered. You can get it close by using the formulas to put the text in the center cell but that's it. The only way to get it all is VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would love for someone to get me started with some VBA! I have experience with it, but don't even know where to start on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VBA solution. It copies the background and font colors from your `Format` table so, if you want white text, use white text in that table. You may want to tweak the border settings (lines 39 & 47) as well as where it looks for the format conditions to use (lines 27 - 30). This is especially true if your example is a pure mockup with little relationship to your real data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MadeFormattedHeadings()

    'Declarations
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim headerRange As Range
    Dim rangeSize As Integer
    Dim rangeStart As Integer
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Integer

    'Choose the worksheet to use
    '(Pick one of these two methods)
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")   'This uses the name on the tab seen in Excel
    Set ws = Sheet1                 'This uses the code name seen in VBA

    With ws

        'Remove previous headers
        If UCase(.Range("A1").Value) = UCase(.Range("A5").Value) Then
            .Rows("1:2").Delete
            .Rows("1:2").Insert
        End If

        'Add new headers
        rangeStart = 1
        For r = 5 To 8  '<<<< There are other methods to iterate. This is just one option.
            'Save the settings
            Set headerRange = .Range("A" & r)
            rangeSize = .Range("B" & r).Value

            'Format the first row
            With .Range(.Cells(1, rangeStart), .Cells(1, rangeStart + rangeSize - 1))
                .Merge
                .Value = headerRange.Value
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Color = headerRange.Font.Color
                .Interior.Color = headerRange.Interior.Color
                .BorderAround xlSolid, xlThin
            End With

            'Format the second row
            With .Range(.Cells(2, rangeStart), .Cells(2, rangeStart + rangeSize - 1))
                .Merge
                .Value = rangeSize
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .BorderAround xlSolid, xlThin
            End With

            'Iterate to the next section
            rangeStart = rangeStart + rangeSize
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is a perfect start to what I needed. Thank you soooo much! Sure wish I could up vote this for you. You are awesome Engineer Toast!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark near the upvote / downvote buttons.